# turtlebot does not bring-up after ROS Groovy Update

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

We working fine with Turtlebot 2 under Groovy
We update ros-groovy, and then, the turtlebot fails to bringup with either minimal or turtlebot launch files.
We got this error

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/xacro.py", line 35, in 
xacro.main()
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 554, in main
process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]))
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 202, in process_includes
raise XacroException("included file "%s" could not be opened: %s" % (filename, str(e)))
xacro.XacroException: included file "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro" could not be opened: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro'
while processing /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/_robot.launch:
Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].

Param xml is

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Any solution for this?

Thanks
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59631/turtlebot-does-not-bring-up-after-ros-groovy-update/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just go to folder:

/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/urdf/

and rename turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro to gazebo.urdf.xacro

---

Originally posted by [antalakas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4575/antalakas/) with karma: 36 on 2013-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurtbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/5174/kurtbra/) on 2013-06-21**:
How can I rename it? It says Permission denied, It doesn't let me change anything.

**Comment by [Mrit91](https://answers.ros.org/users/5003/mrit91/) on 2013-06-28**:
Its rather straight-forward. Type: "gksu nautilus", it will give you the rights to change the root folder.